# Linear Search using coffee script

Tags: coffeescript

I was trying to write coffee script for linear search but I was stuck at point where I have to return a value in addition to value at last line.
Here is my code snippet:

```
Linear_Search = (array, desired) ->
    for x in array
        do ->
            if x is desired
                return true
    false

array = [2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 1, 5]

if Linear_Search(array, 4)
    console.log("Found")
else
    console.log("Not Found")

if Linear_Search(array, 9)
    console.log("Found")
else
    console.log("Not Found")
```

After running this script I got answer to be

`"Not Found"
"Not Found"`

I have tried various things like removing return keyword. But they does not seem to be working. Help me out to learn this awesome technology.

[Compile Online](https://repl.it/C99P)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Thank you but I was actually looking for help in coffeescript.

Comment: javascript *is* coffeescript. That method works the same in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is flawed

```
Linear_Search = (array, desired) ->
    for x in array
        do ->
            if x is desired
                return true
    false
```

should be:

```
Linear_Search = (array, desired) ->
    for x in array
        found = do (x) ->
            x is desired

        return true if found

    false
```

`do` creates an inner function (closure), its response is not being considered in your function. I'm not sure it enhances the function in this case (there may be a reason that I'm wrong on that - somebody with more knowledge will hopefully weigh in if that's the case).

I would write

```
Linear_Search = (array, desired) ->
    for x in array
        return true if x is desired

    false
```

Comment: ["When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments."](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) The `do` isn't needed, the canonical case for `do` is to avoid stray references when building functions inside a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: @RianO'Dwyer its cool to answer questions, and I would not and do not fault you for doing so, its cooler to explain why a question may be the wrong one to ask (google the xy problem). It is highly doubtful the OP really needs to implement linear search in coffeescript (unless its a homework assignment).

Comment: @Jared Smith Fair point. I offered a correction and an alternative to a worked example with a bit of information about why I made the changes. You had already provided the link to what I would have suggested as the proper solution. As for the OP's motives, I took it to be curiosity - rightly or wrongly